# BiometricPrompt crashes the app on rotation / onCreate

Tags: android, kotlin, rotation, fragment, fingerprint

I want to use biometric (fingerprint) login as soon as the app launches.
The app uses a hosting activity and loads the login fragment with biometrics (androidx.biometric:biometric:1.2.0-alpha03). Everything regarding the login works fine but as soon as the phone rotates it crashes. From the log file I understand that the crash happens inside the onCreate because it tries to recreate the FingerprintDialogFragment with an empty constructor.
I tried to cancel the authentication in the onPause function and recreate it manually but that doesn't help. So far my code inside the fragment looks like this:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if(loginSharedPreferences.getBoolean(BIOMETRIC_SET, false)) {
        setupBiometricPrompt()
        biometricPrompt?.authenticate(promptInfo)
    }
}

override fun onPause() {
    if(biometricPrompt != null) {
        biometricPrompt!!.cancelAuthentication()
        biometricPrompt = null
    }
    super.onPause()
}
```

```
private fun setupBiometricPrompt() {
    promptInfo = createBiometricPromptInfo()

    executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext())
    biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(this, executor,
        object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
            override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int,
                                               errString: CharSequence) {
                super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
                Log.d(TAG, "Authentication error: $errString")
            }

            override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(
                result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
                super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
                Log.d(TAG, "Authentication succeeded!")
                callbacks?.loginSuccessful()
            }

            override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
                super.onAuthenticationFailed()
                Log.d(TAG, "Authentication failed!")
            }
        })
}
```

```
private fun createBiometricPromptInfo(): BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo {
    return BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
        .setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.biometric_title))
        .setSubtitle(resources.getString(R.string.biometric_subtitle))
        .setNegativeButtonText(resources.getString(R.string.biometric_cancel))
        .setAllowedAuthenticators(BIOMETRIC_STRONG)
        .build()
}
```

And the log file:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment androidx.biometric.FingerprintDialogFragment: could not find Fragment constructor
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3114)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5039)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4948)
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment androidx.biometric.FingerprintDialogFragment: could not find Fragment constructor
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:628)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:483)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.<init>(FragmentStateManager.java:85)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.restoreSaveState(FragmentManager.java:2728)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreChildFragmentState(Fragment.java:1890)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreate(Fragment.java:1867)
at com.tetraguard.android.otp.LoginPinFragment.onCreate(LoginPinFragment.kt:59)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2949)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:475)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:278)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:3061)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreate(FragmentController.java:240)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:276)
at com.tetraguard.android.otp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:61)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3094)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5039) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4948) 
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965) 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: androidx.biometric.FingerprintDialogFragment.<init> []
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2328)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1725)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:613)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57) 
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:483) 
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.<init>(FragmentStateManager.java:85) 
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.restoreSaveState(FragmentManager.java:2728) 
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreChildFragmentState(Fragment.java:1890) 
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreate(Fragment.java:1867) 
at com.tetraguard.android.otp.LoginPinFragment.onCreate(LoginPinFragment.kt:59) 
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2949) 
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:475) 
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:278) 
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112) 
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647) 
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128) 
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:3061) 
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreate(FragmentController.java:240) 
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:276) 
at com.tetraguard.android.otp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:61) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3094) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5039) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4948) 
at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Comment: `1.2.0-alpha03` - feel free to report a bug

Comment: https://androidx.tech/artifacts/biometric/biometric/1.2.0-alpha03-source/androidx/biometric/FingerprintDialogFragment.java.html ... hehe they made parameterless constructor private ... lame

Comment: Happens with 1.0.0 as well

Comment: *All subclasses of Fragment **must include a public no-argument constructor**. The framework will often re-instantiate a fragment class when needed, in particular during state restore, and needs to be able to find this constructor to instantiate it. If the no-argument constructor is not available, a runtime exception will occur in some cases during state restore.* -- from Google's Fragment docs. Hehe, and what they did ? They did it private.

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't help me..

Comment: Seriously, report a bug and wait, until they fix it. Just disable rotation for given Activity...  But I'm pretty sure that it will gave the exception also when you open other app and return to your after some time

Comment: I've opened a bug report. But any suggestions for a workaround?

Comment: Could you please share the reference to created ticket? I have the same issue which happens in debug mode, once i set (minifyEnabled true) and enable proguard rules - the crash is not reproducible anymore.

Comment: Half a year has passed until this error is reported. Yet the issue is there in 1.2.0-alpha04

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been reported to the Google issue tracker. Might be better to follow the discussion here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/181805603